# How to count to cusps of the modular curve $X_1(N)$, i.e., for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_1(N)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-curves

I already saw the calculations in the book of Diamond and Shurman pag 103 to count the number of cusps of $\Gamma_0(N)$ $(N>1)$ but I really can not understand how to do the calculations for $\Gamma_1(N)$ with $(N>1)$.

The calculation of the book is:

The To count the cusps of $\gamma_0(N)$ recall from Proposition 3.8.3 that for this group, vectors $\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
c
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
a'\\ 
c'
\end{bmatrix}$ with $\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(a′,c′)=1$
represent the same cusp when $\begin{bmatrix}
ya'\\ 
c'
\end{bmatrix}\equiv \begin{bmatrix}
a+jc\\ 
c
\end{bmatrix} \mod N$ for some $j$ and $y$ with $\gcd(y,N)=1$. The bottom condition, $c′\equiv yc \mod N$  for some such $y$, is equivalent to $\gcd(c′,N)=\gcd(c,N)$, in wich case letting $d=\gcd(c,N)$ and letting $y_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy $y_0\equiv c′c^{−1} \mod N$ makes the condition equivalent to $y\equiv y_0+iN/d \mod N$  for some $i$
(confirming the calculations in the paragraph is Exercise 3.8.4.). For any divisor $d$ of $N$, pick one value $c$ modulo $N$
such that $\gcd(c,n)=d$. Then any cusp of $\Gamma_0(N)$
represented by some vector $\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
c
\end{bmatrix}$ with $\gcd(c′,N)=d$ is also represented by $\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
c
\end{bmatrix}$ whenever $(y_0+iN/d)a′\equiv a+jc\mod N$ for some $i$
and $j$ , or $a\equiv y_0a′\mod \gcd(c,N,a′N/d)$, or $a\equiv y_0a′\mod \gcd(d,N/d)$. Also, $a$ is relatively prime to $d$ since $\gcd(a,d)∣\gcd(a,c)=1$, so $a$ is relatively prime to $\gcd(d,N/d)$. Thus for each divisor $d$ of $N$ there are $\phi(\gcd(d,N/d))$
cusps, and the number of cusps of $\Gamma_0(N)$ is therefore $\sum _{d∣N}\phi(\gcd(d,N/d))$.

There is an alternative calculation which is easier and very understandable for the cusps of $\Gamma_0(N)$ in [How does this argument to count the cusps of $Γ_0 (N)$ work?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132494/how-does-this-argument-to-count-the-cusps-of-%ce%93-0-n-work/447120#447120) but I do not understand how to used to get the number of the cusps of $\Gamma_1(N), N>1$.

Any help will be very very important, thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, sure, I will edit my question and write the calculations. Thank you very much for the suggestion. (I am new here but I really want to learn)

Comment: Welcome to MO, and thanks for editing in the details of the calculation!  Can you say where in the calculation you are stuck or confused?

Comment: Thank you very much! 
For $\Gamma_0(N)$ everything is clear to me but for the other congruence subgroup $\Gamma_1(N)$ I do not know how to do the calculation. I thought that maybe it could be analogous to the one I posted but it seems something change or maybe I am misunderstanding something :(

Answer (score 1):

A good reference is Miyake, *Modular forms* (Springer, 1989), Section 4.2. There is an explicit bijection between the set of cusps of $X_1(N)(\mathbf{C})$ and the set
\begin{equation*}
\bigl\{(c,d) : c \in \mathbf{Z}/N\mathbf{Z}, \, d \in (\mathbf{Z}/(c,N)\mathbf{Z})^\times \bigr\}/\{\pm 1\}.
\end{equation*}
Explicitly, for $\gamma = (\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}) \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, the cusp $\Gamma_1(N) \cdot \frac{a}{c} = \Gamma_1(N) \cdot \gamma \infty \in \Gamma_1(N) \backslash \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q})$ corresponds to the class of the pair $(c,d)$. From this one can compute the number of cusps of $X_1(N)(\mathbf{C})$. For $N=1,2,4$, the modular curve $X_1(N)(\mathbf{C})$ has $1,2,3$ cusps respectively, and for $N \neq 1,2,4$, the number of cusps of $X_1(N)(\mathbf{C})$ is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{N}{2} \prod_{p | N} \Bigl( 1- p^{-2} + v_p(N)(1-p^{-1})^2 \Bigr)
\end{equation*}
where the product is over the prime divisors $p$ of $N$, and $v_p(N)$ denotes the $p$-adic valuation of $N$. (This can be deduced from Theorem 4.2.9 in Miyake, using the fact that the RHS of that theorem involves a multiplicative function of $N$.)

For example, if $N=p$ is prime, the modular curve $X_1(p)(\mathbf{C})$ has $(p-1)$ cusps: half of them are above the cusp $\infty \in X_0(p)(\mathbf{Q})$, and the other half above the cusp $0 \in X_0(p)(\mathbf{Q})$.

The set of cusps of $X_1(N)(\mathbf{C})$ is endowed with an action of the Galois group $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{C}/\mathbf{Q})$ and it is easier to cound the number of Galois orbits. Namely, a complete set of representatives of the Galois orbits of cusps in $X_1(N)(\mathbf{C})$ is given by the cusps $\frac{1}{k}$ with $0 \leq k \leq \lfloor \frac{N}{2} \rfloor$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I just have some doubts about it: 1. It is not so clear to me how the calculations works, I mean I don't understand how to get the number of the cusp for the case $X_1(\mathbb{C})$, could you please help me to understand this calculations. 2. I saw the reference and it is confusing to me how to deduce the formula. 3. We now know how to count the cusp, now I am wondering if there is some way to know which one are the cusp, explicitly? Do you know some way to do it? For example as we can do with $X(1)$: we know that the cusp is just one point, $\{\infty\}$.

Comment: Dear @María, what point exactly in the computation is not clear? Something here or in Miyake? The only thing in my answer which is not in Miyake is the formula for the number of cusps as a product over the prime divisors of $N$. Does the confusion lie in going from Miyake's formula to that formula? Regarding 3., once you have understood Miyake, yes you will be able to enumerate the cusps.